# Controlling specific style of the last item of *ngFor

Tags: html, css, angular

I need to make the last line of controls generated by an iterator both disabled and somewhat invisible. I'm using the following, working, code.

```
<div *ngFor="let item of data; let last = last;">

  <input class="form-control"
        [value]="item.e"
        [disabled]="last">

  <button (click)="onRemove(item)"
          class="btn btn-outline-danger"
          [style.visibility]="last?'hidden':''">Do</button>

</div>
```

I'd like to improve the code quality and I'm especially unhappy about the visibility management. When we look at setting disability, it's pretty neat. But the conditional for visibility seems so clunky.

How should the visibility be controlled like-a-boss'ly?

I tested the following, with no luck.

```
<button (click)="onRemove(item)"
        class="btn btn-outline-danger"
        [style.visibility.hidden]="last">Do</button>
```

Comment: I've seen much worse Angular template code, this looks pretty good. But I guess you could do `[style.visibility]="last && 'hidden'"`. If `last` is `true`, `last && 'hidden'`  will evaluate to `'hidden'`, otherwise it will evaluate to `undefined`

Comment: I agree with @ShamPooSham and I find his suggestion simple and clean. For the sake of conversation you can also use [ngClass]="{'hidden': last}" and then create a css class .hidden: { visibility: hidden }.

Comment: @ShamPooSham Post your comment as an answer, please.

Comment: @SoCo I was considering it but got uncertain. Check the comment I made to the posted answer for reason why.

Comment: Thank you. I edited my answer to be a bit more correct in my statements and added further reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go with creating a class (might be global if used heavily) for invisible item

```css
.invisible {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

Then apply the class according to `last` value

```
<button (click)="onRemove(item)" 
        class="btn btn-outline-danger"
        [class.invisible]="last">
</button>
```

Example in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yd81ae?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: I was leaning towards that too. The reason I rejected it was that I'd be using SCSS for hiding the button while I'm doing the disabling of the input directly in HTML. It's logically two parts of the same requirement so it made sense to perform both in the same file. Thoughts on that?

Comment: @KonradViltersten I am feeling what you say. Well on my view since we talking about pressentation logic and templating and since both .html and .scss files are part of the pressentation part of Angular, I personally find Tal's suggestion clean and predictable.

Comment: @KonradViltersten I agree with @SoCo, also I think, `hidden` is for style only, so it's ok that it sits in a style-related file, when `disabled` has more to do with the element's logic

Answer (score 2):

You could do `[style.visibility]="last && 'hidden'"`.

If `last` is `truthy`, `last && 'hidden'` will evaluate to `'hidden'`, otherwise it will evaluate to whatever `falsy` value it's set to. When a style is set using the `[style.property]` syntax, and the value is `falsy`, it will simply not be set.

Read more about truthy and falsy values [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/) and how you can use short-curcuit logic to evaluate values in a elegant way [here](https://dev.to/akhil_001/replacing-the-if-else-conditionals-with-logical-operators-and-4hek) .

That said, I think your solution is clean enough and probably more clear for some people (which is important if someone else is going to read your code).